# cant install selenium wire

Tags: python, seleniumwire

```
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        F
      distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvTon.png)it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is written in your console.

```
distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required.
```

just install the latest build here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/